# drop down list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have something basic generated from `nifty_scaffold` in a partial form: `_form.html.erb`

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :group_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :group_id %>
  </p>
```

Instead of a text field I want to convert the above from text_field to a drop down list which will be populated with `groups` which I set below.

My `new` action in `Employee` controller looks like this:

```
  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
    @groups = Group.all
  end
```

How do I make a drop down list where it will be populated with all groups in `@groups` variable

Additionally, how will `edit` action work? there I will want the assigned group to be preselected.  Since I am using a partial form, same form will be used in `edit` as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%=  select("employee", "group_id", Group.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true })%>
```

works!